# how can i connect to aws fron vscode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I'm having an error while trying to connect my Aws account on vscode. the error message reads " " cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'record')"

I used the terminal which works perfectly but still shows error while i retry command palette.

I'm using aws toolkit from the extension. I keep getting error every I use the "aws: create credentials profile" command but aws configure works perfectly well in terminal.

I've done the configuration in terminal but it seems like I need to connect my vscode to my aws in order to used the aws explore.

Comment: Sorry, but you have not provided enough detail in your question for us to assist you. Please tell us more about how you are "trying to connect my Aws account on vscode". For example, are you using an Extension? Which one? What have you configured and what commands are you trying? Please Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: I'm so sorry about that. I've added more details.